# prove this $\sqrt{2}-1\le 4\sin{\frac{A}{2}}\sin{\frac{B}{2}}\sin{\frac{C}{2}}$

Tags: inequality

In any acute triangle $\Delta ABC,min{(A,B,C)}\ge\dfrac{\pi}{4}$,Prove that
$$\sqrt{2}-1\le 4\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}$$

since
$$4\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}=2\left[\cos{\dfrac{A-B}{2}}-\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}\right]\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}$$

Comment: The lower limit must be wrong. Take $A=2^o,B=C=89^o$, then $4\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}=0.03<\sqrt2-1$.

Comment: @almagest Using `^\circ` gives a much nicer degree symbol than `^o`: $45^\circ$ vs $45^o$.

Comment: So the correct inequality is $0\le\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}\le\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can find the upper bound as follows:

$$2\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2=\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\cos\dfrac{A+B}2=\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\sin\dfrac C2$$

If $y=4\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\sin\dfrac C2=2\sin\dfrac C2\left(\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-\sin\dfrac C2\right)$

$\iff2\sin^2\dfrac C2-2\sin\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+y=0$

As $\sin\dfrac C2$ is real, the discriminant  $$\left(2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2\right)^2-8y\ge0\iff2y\le\cos\dfrac{A-B}2\le1$$

The equality occurs if $A=B$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\log (\sin x)$ is concave for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$, so Jensen's inequality will give you the maximum and the minimum is when one variable hits the boundary...